# Self Message vs Return Message in Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

What the difference between a self message and a return message.
Here 2 examples:

**Self Message:**

[image: self message]

**Return Message:**

[image: return message]

Which example is correct?

Answer (score 2):

### When lifelines are objects

A self-message is a message like any other, except that it has a special addressee. Typically you would implement the first example by having one operation of a class call another operation of the same object. Pseudocode:

```
class WebInterface {
  …
  public void showList() {
     …
     display();
     …
  }
  public void display() {
     …
  }
  …
}
```

A return message provides a result back to the caller. Typically for a synchronous message implemented with a call of an operation, it would correspond to the return of the value. Pseudocode:

```
class WebInterface {
  …
  public Display showList() {
     Display display;
     …
     return display;
  }
  …
}
```

### When an actor is involved

In your examples, you use an actor in the sequence diagram. In principle, an actor is external to the system whereas a sequence diagram shows message exchanges **within** the system. Although this practice is popular, it is ambiguous, because no semantics are defined for exchanging messages with a human being.

In this particular context it’s a more **informal** meaning :

- Both examples suggest
  interactions of a subsystem with a user instead of formal message exchange between objects. In both cases, the user would activate some button or menu that would tell the web interface that it should show a list.
- In the first example, the explicit call of a `display` operation within the web interface suggests that some displaying would take place. We  ***implicitly*** understand that the user would get some visual feedback.
- In the second example, the return message suggests ***explicitly** a feedback to the user, in form of a displayed result.

Comment: Plus the message signature should end with the parameter list in brackets, while the return message shows the _virtual_ result.

Comment: It seems both ways have the same purpose but there's a difference in the codes.

Comment: @Haru yes, difference in the “code”, indeed. But same purpose only in this context, and in similar diagrams involving actors.

Answer (score 0):

The self message is a message to self, and the reply message (you called it "return message") is a message to the sender of the preceeding synchroneous message. It is tied to this synchroneous message and as such cannot have an own name ("display"). It is always assumed to be there, even if you didn't model it in the second case. It can define a return value, but it would be shown after a colon. So the correct label on it would be

```
showing list:"some text"
```

It is OK to leave out the message name, but the colon should always be there when a return value is needed.

See the UML specification:

> **section 17.4.4.1 Message**
>
> A reply-message-label is used for reply
> Messages. It has the following form: *<reply-message-label> ::=
> [<assignment-target> ‘=’] <message-name>  [‘(’
> [<output-argument-list>] ‘)’] [‘:’ <value-specification>]*

As @Christophe has pointed out in his answer, the semantics of messages involving humans is not clearly defined. This is especially true for synchroneous messages. I would argue, that they don't make sense at all in real life situations. After sending a synchroneous message, the sender is supposed to wait for the reply message. I think it is not possible to force a human to do that. Therefore, I recommend to use asynchroneous messages here. For example, the display message to self could lead to an asynchroneous message being sent to the customer.

Comment: The colon is not required. In the UML specification, the colon is inside the square brackets and therefore optional. The message name, however, is required when using a replay-message-label.

Comment: The colon is required, if you, as in this case, want to specify a return value. The message name is mandatory in the BNF. However, later in the text it says: "_If the identity of a reply Message is obvious (e.g., when its sendEvent is the only reply within the extent of an ExecutionOccurence where there is only one receipt of an Operation call message), the label may be omitted_". Ok, that would include the return value, but since this is not formally specified and it simply makes sense to show it, I think my interpretation might well be the original intent of the specification author.